# Configuring Web Logic JMS Module with Oracle AQ Queues

Tags: jndi, weblogic11g, oracle-aq

I testing setting up a web logic server which can use an Oracle AQ JMS implementation, but for some reason my WLS connection pool cannot see the queue I have created, the only way I can see the find the queue in web logic is to make the web logic datasource connection pool use the credentials of the DB user who created the queue.

I have done the following as  admin_user:

**Created a Queue Table**

```
EXECUTE DBMS_AQADM.CREATE_QUEUE_TABLE(queue_table=>'testqueue_table',queue_payload_type=>'sys.aq$_jms_text_message');
```

**Created a Queue**

```
EXECUTE dbms_aqadm.create_queue(queue_name=>'testqueue', queue_table=>'testqueue_table');
```

**Started the Queue**

```
EXECUTE dbms_aqadm.start_queue(queue_name=>'testqueue');
```

**Granted the CPOOL user permissions**

```
GRANT aq_user_role TO cpool;
EXECUTE DBMS_AQADM.grant_queue_privilege(privilege=>'ALL', queue_name=>'adming_user.testqueue', grantee=>'cpool',grant_option=>FALSE);
```

**Set up 2 JDBC DataSources in Web Logic**
I set up 2 datasources in web logic which connect to my database, both are identical except that one uses the **cpool** user and the other uses **admin_user**

**Create JMS Modules**
Now I register a jms module with the JDBC DataSources and wire up the local and foreign JDNI names.

If I use the DataSource which uses **admin_user** everything works fine and my deployed application can find queue in JNDI.

**Problem**
If I use the data source which uses **cpool** then it fails finds the connection pool in JNDI but never the Queue (despite the fact it worked for admin_user). I get the following error from WL:

```
Related cause:org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'testqueue': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Cannot resolve name:Queues/TESTQUEUE
```

Does anyone know why WL cannot resolve the JNDI name for the queue unless I use the admin_user account for my datasource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was that my connection pool user was missing some grants, the following where required:

```
GRANT EXECUTE on DBMS_AQ to <CPOOL>;
GRANT EXECUTE on DBMS_AQADM to <CPOOL>;
GRANT aq_user_role to <CPOOL>;
```

Make sure the user who creates the destination grants access to the connection pool user:

```
`EXECUTE DBMS_AQADM.grant_queue_privilege(privilege=>'ALL', queue_name=>'<SCHEMAOWNER>.docprod_queue', grantee=>'<CPOOL>',grant_option=>FALSE);`
```

Finally in Web Logic make sure to reference the destination by their full foreign JNDI name:

```
Queues/<SCHEMA OWNER>.<DESTINATION_NAME>
```